# WSO2 Enterprise Store : New asset type

Tags: app-store, wso2, assets, lifecycle, wso2-es

Can i build a new asset type with predefined categories and based on each category provide a diferent LifeCycle Management and also diferent attributes of metadata ? (ex: ebooks for IT Category have a diferent lifecycle and diferent attributes of metadata)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment(ES-1.2.0 M2) you can only have one life-cycle definition for a given artifact type.